# Can't send commands to server via Serial connection in putty/termite

Tags: putty, serial, sun

I acquired a Sunfire v215 server from work (they were recycling it) to fiddle around with in my spare time. I'm trying to start it up - the installation guide says you need to use a serial terminal or terminal emulator (currently using putty) to access the SC/ALOM.

I'm using a USB to DB9 converter and DB9 to RJ45 with a straight through cable to connect to the serial management port on the machine.

After powering on the server, I'm able to see the output in the console, but the machine does not appear to receive any commands from me.

Output is as follows:

```
[00]
ALOM BOOTMON v1.6.4
ALOM Build Release: 002
Reset register: e0000000 EHRS ESRS LLRS


ALOM POST 1.0


Dual Port Memory Test, PASSED.


TTY External - Internal Loopback Test


TTY External - Internal Loopback Test, PASSED.


TTYC - Internal Loopback Test


TTYC - Internal Loopback Test, PASSED.


TTYD - Internal Loopback Test


TTYD - Internal Loopback Test, PASSED.


Memory Data Lines Test
Memory Data Lines Test, PASSED.


Memory Address Lines Test
  Slide address bits to test open address lines

  Test for shorted address lines

Memory Address Lines Test, PASSED.


Boot Sector FLASH CRC Test
Boot Sector FLASH CRC Test, PASSED.




Return to Boot Monitor for Handshake  
ALOM POST 1.0
   Status = 00007fff


Returned from Boot Monitor and Handshake




Loading the runtime image... 

Sun(tm) Advanced Lights Out Manager 1.6.4 (sun-srv02)




Full VxDiag Tests


BASIC TOD TEST

  Read the TOD Clock:        WED AUG 02 05:03:56 2017

  Wait, 1 - 3 seconds        

  Read the TOD Clock:        WED AUG 02 05:03:58 2017

BASIC TOD TEST, PASSED


ETHERNET CPU LOOPBACK TEST

  50 BYTE PACKET   - a 0 in field of 1's.  

  50 BYTE PACKET   - a 1 in field of 0's.  

  900 BYTE PACKET  - pseudo-random data.  

ETHERNET CPU LOOPBACK TEST, PASSED


Full VxDiag Tests - PASSED




    Status summary  -  Status = 7FFF


       VxDiag    -          -  PASSED

       POST      -          -  PASSED

       LOOPBACK  -          -  PASSED


       I2C       -          -  PASSED

       EPROM     -          -  PASSED

       FRU PROM  -          -  PASSED


       ETHERNET  -          -  PASSED

       MAIN CRC  -          -  PASSED

       BOOT CRC  -          -  PASSED


       TTYD      -          -  PASSED

       MEMORY    -          -  PASSED           TTYC      -          -  PASSED



       MPC885    -          -  PASSED



Please login: 
SC Alert: SC System booted.
```

After a few minutes, the system times out, regardless of how much I try to type, and I'm left with the following:

```
Serial line login timeout, returns to console stream.

Enter #. to return to ALOM
```

What would cause a serial connection to act as if it were "read-only?"

Edit: Serial configuration being used follows the Installation Guide https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19088-01/v245.srvr/819-3037-10/819-3037-10.pdf

```
9600 baud
8 bits
no parity
1 stop bit
no handshaking
```

Comment: Please show your serial configuration. Try to disable/enable flow-control, on Cisco devices it helps.

Comment: Updated post with serial config.  I cycled through all the options for flow control with no change in result.